# Why does ISPF move/copy succeed despite ENQs while IEBCOPY fails?

Tags: mainframe

Why is it that when I submit a job to copy a member from one library to another

```
//STEP010  EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=(,),OUTPUT=(*.STD1)   
//SYSUT1   DD DSN=USER1.SOURCE.JCL,             
//            DISP=SHR                     
//SYSUT2   DD DSN=USER2.TARGET.JCL,   
//            DISP=(OLD,KEEP)              
//SYSIN    DD *                            
  COPY OUTDD=SYSUT2,INDD=SYSUT1            
  SELECT MEMBER=(SOMEJCL)                 
/*
```

and I get a message that the target library is not available because it's being held by someone else,

```
IEF863I DSN = USER2.TARGET.JCL J0000001 RC = 04 RSN = 00000000 FROM SERVICE ENQ
IEF099I JOB J0000001 WAITING FOR DATA SETS
```

I'm able to use ISPF panel 3.4 (move/copy) and copy the member despite another user still holding the target library?  In other words, what is ISPF doing that IEBCOPY is not doing?

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

You're requesting exclusive control over data set `USER2.TARGET.JCL` by specifying `DISP=OLD` on the `DD` statement. That other user has (directly or indirectly) requested, and received *shared* access by specifying `DISP=SHR`. ISPF in your session also does a *shared* request when you access the data set, say, in ISPF 3.4. This is why you can access the data set in ISPF but your job has to wait until all shared access request will be abandoned, before it is allowed to run.

## Details to Exlain the Short Answer

### Service ENQ? What is this?

You got a message from *Service ENQ* telling you that the data set is in use by some other task (~process).
In contrast to other operating systems, IBM z/OS requires (except for very special cases) that the task which wants to access a data set (~file) specifies whether it needs exclusive control of the data set, or whether shared access is allowed.
In z/OS *JCL*, you specify this via the `DISP=` parameter on the `DD` statement. `DISP=NEW`, `DISP=OLD`, and `DISP=MOD` tells the system that exclusive control is needed. `DISP=SHR` (SHR for shared) on the other side tells the system that multiple tasks can access the data set simultaneously.
The system internally uses the *ENQUEUE* system service (API) to keep track of such access requests. (The ENQUEUE service is a general service, not limited to data set usage.) Read more about this concept in z/OS manual ["z/OS MVS Programming - Assembler Services Guide"](https://www-01.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R4sa231368/$file/ieaa600_v2r4.pdf), chapter 6 "Resource Control", topic "Serializing access to resources (ISGENQ macro)".
The enqueue service is a general concept to serialize access to any kind of resource, data sets being one kind. It asks for four parameters: A *queue name* (*qname* hereafter), a *resource name* (*rname* hereafter), the *access level* (shared or exclusive), and a *scope*. For simplicity, I don't talk about the scope here. Protection only works if each and every single program adheres to agreed upon queue and resource names to protect resources.

#### Displaying the Enqueues your TSO Session holds

In case of data sets, the agreed upon *qname* is "SYSDSN", and the agreed upon *rname* is the name of the data set.
You can display the *enqueues* that your ISPF session (more correctly, your TSO session address space) is holding by typing

```
TSO ISRDDN E
```

on any ISPF command line. This will display the list of enqueues matching the search criteria. *Major name prefix* means qname (prefix).
Type "SYSDSN" to get a list of data sets. *Minor name prefix* means the rname, which is the "data set name" (when the major name is "SYSDSN"). Type PF1 to get help for what is shown to you.
IBM z/OS manual "[z/OS MVS Diagnosis - Reference](https://www-01.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R4ga320904/$file/ieav200_v2r4.pdf)", chapter 6 "Serialization summary", topic "ENQ/DEQ summary" has a list of qnames, and rnames that the system uses with a very brief information about what this is. Remember, you can invent your own qnames/rnames to serialize your resource, and this is being used by many program products that you may be using on your system. So, there are more names you might find.

#### From JCL to Enqueue

Specifying, say, `DSN=YOURID.SOME.DATA.SET,DISP=SHR` on a `DD` statement in a job will lead to an enqueue request being issues behind the scenes, with qname="SYSDSN", rname="YOURID.SOME.DATA.SET", and access level "shared". The system will verify that *no other task* in the system is currently holding an *exclusive* level enqueue to the same qname/rname pair, i.e. to the same data set. If none does, your job is allowed to run, otherwise, it is put onto a waiting queue until the exclusive access is released. This is the situation when you see the message you posted.

#### Shared versus Exclusive Access to Data Sets

A data set can only ever be written to from a single task at the same time. I.e. the task needs exclusive control over the data set when it wants to write to it. Therefore you specify `DISP=OLD` on the `DD` statement, which leads to an *exclusive enqueue* request. Your job then needs to wait until no single other task has neither *shared*, nor *exclusive* access.
On the other hand, many tasks are allowed to *read* a data set in parallel. You specify `DISP=SHR` when you only read from but do not write to the data set.

#### Data Sets with Members

Data sets which contain *members*, i.e. other kinda "data sets", are no different. There are two kinds of such data sets: PDSs, and PDSEs. The system does *not* include the member name your accessing when issuing the *enqueue* request. You request exclusive control over the data set, no matter what member your working with, when you're gonna write to a member. This is quite coarse, and may lock out many users that need to access *other* members in the same data set at the same time. To bring some relief to this, ISPF has implemented an enhancement.

#### Qname=SPFEDIT to Help with PDS/PDSE Usage

ISPF has introduced another qname to be used with *members* of PDSs, and PDSEs: "SPFEDIT". The resource name is built from the data set name, as with qname="SYSDSN", but the *member* name is appended to it. When you access a PDS, or PDSE in ISPF, a data set level enqueue with access level "shared", as described above, is being issued. When you *edit* a member thereafter, ISPF issues another enqueue request. This time an *exclusive* request with qname=SPFEDIT, and rname="dsn member". Your member is protected from being written to simultaneously, but others can still *read* the (old) content of the member at the same time, since *no* qname="SPFEDIT" request is issued to read access.

#### System Utility IEBCOPY - UPDATED

I initially wrote: "The system utility *IEBCOPY* has taken over this concept from ISPF, ...", and I did this based on false memory, it seems.

Unfortunately, I could not (yet) find a proof of this, so I'm deleting that paragraph. At least for the time being.

#### PDSs versus PDSEs

PDSs are the legacy implementation of data sets with members. They only ever allow one single process to write to at any give point in time.
PDSEs on the other hand are newer, and allow parallel write access, as long as the members are different ones.
Therefore, you may be editing one member in a given data set, and another user may be editing a different member in the same PDSE type data set. This is not allowed with PDS type data sets. It is more complex than I want to go into here. Just think about that "at the time" as seen from the user may actually be "one after the other" in as quick systems as today.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Please take note of my update in paragraph *System Utility IEBCOPY*.

Comment: Your statement "_you may be editing one member in a given data set, and another user may be editing a different member in the same PDSE type data set. This is not allowed with PDS type data sets._"  is not correct.   Multiple people have always been able to edit different members in the same dataset at the same time ISPF editor from day 1.  This is why the SPFEDIT ENQ was invented.

Comment: @GOVarney ISPF's SPFEDIT enqueue is a workaround, and I have mentioned it. The access method itself does *not* support it.

Answer (score 1):

The JCL has a disposition of *DISP=OLD* which means I want exclusive use of the PDS.

```
//SYSUT2   DD DSN=USER2.TARGET.JCL,   
//            DISP=(OLD,KEEP)
```

in ISPF you would have **DISP=SHR**. Using DISP=SHR with IEBCOPY could corrupt the file (this is rare), ISPF has its own internal checks to make sure ISPF users to make sure only one ISPF updates the PDS catalog at the same time.

You could use DISP=SHR in the Job but it would not be a safe operation. Alternatively you could run ISPF in the job and do the copy.